# Does Naive Bayes( library:klar) in R calculates denominator of conditional probability while giving output?

Tags: r, conditional-probability, naive-bayes

Generally, when using Naive Bayes for classification, denominator is ignored as probability is directly proportional to the numerator as denominator is same for all the classes. 
So, I want to know if Naive Bayes in R includes denominator calculation while giving/predicting output for the values other than training data ?

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt [from the documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/klaR/docs/NaiveBayes):

> **Values**
>
> An object of class "NaiveBayes" including components:
>
> `apriori`
>       Class distribution for the dependent variable.
>   `tables`
>       A list of tables, one for each predictor variable. For each categorical variable a table giving, for each attribute level, the  conditional probabilities given the target class. For each numeric
>   variable, a table giving, for each target class, mean and standard
>   deviation of the (sub-)variable or a object of class density.

So the output depends on the input type. As about probabilities: *if* it is said that the software returns probabilities, then they need to be normalized (i.e. the denominator needs to be used), because otherwise they wouldn't be probabilities (the numbers would not agree with the [axioms of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms)).